# how to prevent drools engine looping on entry point data

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, rule-engine, entry-point

I'm using drools to raise alarm on streaming transaction data.
The drools engine is STREAM and ACTIVE mode. I also use an entry point (OM-TRANS) to transmit data to the rule engine.
I have written a simple rule to test the behaviour of the engine. I got some results but i don't understand them and their are not what i expect.

This is the first simple rule:

```
rule "My rule"
    no-loop true
    when
        $transaction: TransactionOmDto($msisdn: msisdn) from entry-point "OM-TRANS"
    then
        System.out.println("------------ an alarm on "+$msisdn+" ----------");
    end
```

These are the results i got after testing:

1. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_1***:

`------------ an alarm on msisdn_1 ----------`

2. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_1*** again:

`------------ an alarm on msisdn_1 ----------`

3. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_2***:

`------------ an alarm on msisdn_2 ----------`

4. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_2*** again:

`------------ an alarm on msisdn_2 ----------`

5. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_3***:

`------------ an alarm on msisdn_3 ----------`

This is now the second version of the rule:

```
rule "My rule"
    no-loop true
    when
        $transaction: TransactionOmDto($msisdn: msisdn) from entry-point "OM-TRANS"
        $datasTransaction: List() from collect(TransactionOmDto(msisdn == $msisdn) from entry-point "OM-TRANS")
    then
        System.out.println("------------ an alarm on "+$msisdn+", total Transaction: "+$datasTransaction.size()+" ----------");
    end
```

and i got the following results and what i expect:

1. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_1***:

`------------ an alarm on msisdn_1, total Transaction: 1 ----------`
(this is the one expected)

2. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_1*** again:

```
------------ an alarm on msisdn_1, total Transaction: 2 ----------
------------ an alarm on msisdn_1, total Transaction: 2 ----------
```

*What i expected is :* A sigle row **------------ an alarm on msisdn_1, total Transaction: 2 ----------**

3. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_2***:

`------------ an alarm on msisdn_2, total Transaction: 1 ----------` (as expected)

4. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_2*** again:

```
------------ an alarm on msisdn_2, total Transaction: 2 ----------
------------ an alarm on msisdn_2, total Transaction: 2 ----------
```

*What i expected is :* A sigle row **------------ an alarm on msisdn_2, total Transaction: 2 ----------**

5. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_3***:

`------------ an alarm on msisdn_3, total Transaction: 1 ----------`
(this is the one expected)

6. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_3*** again:

```
------------ an alarm on msisdn_3, total Transaction: 2 ----------
------------ an alarm on msisdn_3, total Transaction: 2 ----------
```

*What i expected is :* A sigle row **------------ an alarm on msisdn_3, total Transaction: 2 ----------**

7. transaction from msisdn ***msisdn_3*** again:

```
------------ an alarm on msisdn_3, total Transaction: 3 ----------
------------ an alarm on msisdn_3, total Transaction: 3 ----------
------------ an alarm on msisdn_3, total Transaction: 3 ----------
```

*What i expected is :* A sigle row **------------ an alarm on msisdn_3, total Transaction: 3 ----------**

Can someone explain to me why i got those result?
Is it possible to get what i expect ?
Thanks you.

Comment: Are you just trying to get a count of alarms? Because your current workflow is going to eventually run out of memory unless you configure those events to expire, which will additionally throw off your "totals".

Comment: yes, i have configure the event to expire:                                                     `declare TransactionOmDto
    @role(event)
    @timestamp(date)
    @expires(24h)
end`

Comment: Yeah you probably want to use a sliding window like Mike suggests in the answers. The `collect(...) from entry-point` is effectively replaying the previous events.

Comment: Hello Roddy of the Frozen Peas. I have test Mike's code. The size of the list **_$datasTransaction_** is always 0:

`------------ an alarm on msisdn_1, total Transaction: 0 ----------`

Comment: Are you trying to get the count of all matching events _ever_ received from that entry-point, or just the ones in the past 24h window?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to get all matching receive event from the entry-point, each time i receive a new event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your events expire only in 24h, older ones do participate in the rule logic.
Usually this can be fixed with sliding length window

```
 over window:length(1) from entry-point "OM-TRANS"
```

full snippet

```
rule "My rule2"
no-loop true
when
    $transaction: TransactionOmDto($msisdn: msisdn) over window:length(1) from entry-point "OM-TRANS"
    $datasTransaction: List() from collect(TransactionOmDto(msisdn == $msisdn) from entry-point "OM-TRANS")
then
    System.out.println("------------ an alarm on "+$msisdn+", total Transaction: "+$datasTransaction.size()+" ----------");
end
```

output

```
------------ an alarm on msisdn_1, total Transaction: 1 ----------
------------ an alarm on msisdn_1, total Transaction: 2 ----------
------------ an alarm on msisdn_1, total Transaction: 3 ----------
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike for your answer.
`$datasTransaction.size()` gives **0** no matter how many TransactionOmDto object I send:

`------------ an alarm on msisdn_1, total Transaction: 0 ----------`

Comment: I got different output, please provide full listing of your rules and scenario (junit test, or snippet from the test)

Comment: Hello Mike. You are right. My rule engine is in STREAM mode with a realtime clock. The datas I was sending to the engine did not have the correct dates. Once corrected, I get exactly the right results.